# How to make JMockit inject a specific instance to a JMockit @Tested class?

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a class that I am trying to test with JMockit 1.49.  My Class-Under-Test uses constructor injection with 2 parameters; one mocked, and one that I want to instantiate within my Test class and have JMockit inject for me.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
public class DocFilterService {

    // get a static slf4j logger for the class
    protected static final Logger logger = getLogger(DocFilterService.class);

    private DocRepository DocRepository;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    public DocFilterService(DocRepository DocRepository, @Doc ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.DocRepository = DocRepository;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    // business method to test
    public DocWrapperDTO filterDoc(Context context, DocWrapperDTO dcfData){
      // some business logic looking to test.
      ... 
    }
}
```

In my JMockit test class I have the following:

```
public class DocFilterServiceTest2 {

    @Mocked @Injectable DocRepository DocRepository;
    @Doc ObjectMapper objectMapper = new DocProducer().getMapper();
    @Tested DocFilterService sut;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void jMockit(){
        Startup.verifyInitialization();
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidResponse() throws IOException {
        // create some valid input
        Context context = Context.ContextBuilder.aContext()
                .user(User.UserBuilder.aUser()
                        .id("123")
                        .build()
                )
                .build();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        new Expectations(){{
            DocRepository.filterDoc( (Body<DocWrapperDTO>) any ); result = mapper.readTree("{\"decision_id\": \"1\"}"); minTimes=1;
        }};


        // todo to fix.  Use a Mock repo and proper parameter
        sut.filterDoc( context, new DocWrapperDTO());

        new Verifications(){{
            DocRepository.filterDoc((Body<DocWrapperDTO>)any);
        }};

    }
}
```

With this configuration, JMockit throws the following Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No constructor in tested class that can be satisfied by available tested/injectable values
  public org.wada.adams.opa.dcf.DcfFilterService(org.wada.adams.opa.dcf.repository.DcfRepository, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper)
    disregarded because no tested/injectable value was found for parameter "objectMapper"
```

If I change the `@Tested` annotation to

```
        @Tested(fullyInitialized=true) DocFilterService sut;
```

then the `ObjectMapper` which is injected into my `sut` is a new instance of the ObjectMapper and not the one declared as the `@Doc ObjectMapper objectMapper = new DocProducer().getMapper();` instance.

I've tried reading the docs on JMockit, and I was under the impression that it should be using any instances declared in my Test class, but it does not seem to be doing that.

How can I specify/declare to JMockit that I want it to use my instance as the injection candidate and not instantiate a new one?  Do I need to declare it as a `@Tested` instance?  It does not seem like the right annotation to use.

Comment: I even tried solving this by using MockUp to give some class a "custom" implementation while still having JMockit think that it's an injectable mock. However that also doesn't appear supported. https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/211. Looks like you're out of luck here. Maybe you could try a subclass of DocFilterService with its own constructor that only exposes the fields which need mocking/injecting. It could just be a static nested class in the test file. Hacky, sure, but technically it's testing the same code while still letting you use `new DocProducer().getMapper()`.

Answer (score 1):

For an @Tested element, JMockit will invoke a construct for which it has @Injectable arguments.  In your case, you need to have both the DocRepository, and the ObjectMapper as @Injectable.   By default, @Injectables are also @Mocked, so you don't need both annotations.  I believe this will work

```
@Injectable DocRepository DocRepository;
@Injectable ObjectMapper objectMapper;
@Tested DocFilterService sut;
```

That said, the above makes objectMapper a mock.  Your original code seems to be trying to use a real instance of it.  Puristically, that's a bad idea because ObjectMapper is a different 'unit', so in the DocFilterService 'unit', we ought to treat it as a black-box and mock it.